# Why Core Animation methods are class methods but not instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

In Core Animation framework, why the methods beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations are class methods of UIView?
Why not being instance methods so we code:

```
[widget beginAnimations:@""];
[widget commitAnimations];
```

instead of:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:widget];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beginAnimations:context:` class method begins an animation "block":

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
view1.frame.x = 10;
view2.opacity = 0.5;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

With the above snippet, `view1` and `view2` will animate the changes inside that block.

The `context` property is NOT the view you want to animate, just information that can be accessed via the delegate methods.

> *context*
>
> Custom data that you want to associate with this set of
>   animations. information that is passed to the animation delegate
>   messages—the selectors set using the setAnimationWillStartSelector:
>   and setAnimationDidStopSelector: methods.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

As a sidenote, this way of performing animations is discouraged in iOS4 and above. If you need to target older iOS versions, check the flag:

```
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    // iOS4 and above
#else
    // iOS3
#endif
```

Comment: That compile-time check will only work if you're also using an older SDK. If you're targeting (e.g.) 3.2 but your compiler/SDK are 4.3, you'll use the blocks code and crash on 3.2 devices.